How to remove DMI solvent from acid sensitive crude reaction mixture?
I performed a reaction in DMI (1,3-Dimethyl-2-imidazolidinone) solvent, which contains acid-sensitive vinyl borinic ester product as shown below.

It has an exact mass of 364.2, whose trace could be found in GC-MS at a residence time of 7.62 minutes.

Since DMI is a high-boiling liquid, it doesn't easily evaporates, nor does the vinyl boronic ester product. I have tried out several kinds of aqueous workup to get rid of the DMI.
I used DCM-water workup, which totally doesn't help (see top EIC spectra ), and DMI is carried into the organic layer.
I have also tried pentane-water (having magnesium salt) workup, which partly helped, but a major DMI peak is retained. (see bottom EIC spectra )
The vinyl borinic ester is an acid-sensitive compound and can undergo protodebornation in the presence of acid and even in the presence of silica which is Lewis-acidic in nature(so column purification cannot be done). I am not sure of using any nitrate salt to remove DMI as suggested in this Reddit thread, lest the borinic ester get oxidized.
I would be very much delighted if someone could suggest to me any method to remove this persistent DMI solvent, keeping the product intact.

A couple of suggestions 1. pentane/MeCN washes  2. Chromatography on alumina

@Waylander  I will try out the triethyl amine treated alumina chromatography now
